# How to show that $\prod^{p-1}\limits_{j=0} (x+\eta^jy)=x^p+y^p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

How to show that

> $\prod^{p-1}\limits_{j=0} (x+\eta^jy)=x^p+y^p$, where $p$ is an odd prime, $\eta$ is $p$-th roots of unity and $x,y$ are integers.

It could be reduced to the form $\prod^{p-1}\limits_{j=0} (1+\eta^ja)=1+a^p$ for $a=\frac y x$, but I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going that way, do
$\prod_{j=0}^{p-1} (a-\eta^j)=a^p -1$ by considering the roots of $a^p -1=0$. Then replace $a$ by $-a$. Then use $a=\frac{x}{y}$.